# how to include a link in an <option> tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I'm having trouble making my list box links work.  I found the following code on this website, but when I preview it in the browser, the link works for the fist option I choose, but if I try a second option, the browser tells me it can't find the page.

```
<select onchange="javascript:handleSelect(this)">

<option value="../Pages/Examples of Business plans/Business plan samples">Agriculture</option>
<option value="../Pages/Examples of Business plans/Business plan samples">Automotive</option>
<option value="../Pages/Examples of Business plans/Business plan samples">Hospitality</option>

</select>

                     <script type="text/javascript">
                     function handleSelect(elm)
                     {
                     window.location = elm.value+".php";
                     }
                     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The file does not exist in that directory.

i.e. There is no file named 'value of the `elm` control' with '.php' appended to it in the directory of the code you are using there.